# Is there a way to scale layers relative to their individual boundaries in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, resize

I am wondering if there is a way, in Photoshop CC, to select multiple layers and then resize them relative to their current location.

For example, if I have 2 equal sized squares next to each other, I want to be able to select them both, then drag the bottom right corner to make them smaller without the location of their top left corners moving.

I realise that you can use shift+click to select multiple layers, then transform them together, but the result of this is that they get smaller and the space between them also gets smaller.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Possibly this can be done with a PhotoShop Action. This discussion might give a hint how to set this up: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/988084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are saying you want to select multiple objects, layers, and have each layer resize respectively to its own upper left corner, correct?

That’s not possible in PS because whether you select multiple 'items', (areas of pixels) and/or layers, there's only one transformation box, having one origin (the point or side that doesn't move).

e.g. let’s say you had a TicTacToe configuration of squares, 4", and you wanted to keep it 4" but reduce each by 50% thereby doubling the space between each of the nine squares.

Yes, in illustrator, no in Photoshop because Photoshop is for photos and really doesn’t have the shape manipulation power that illustrator has (pathfinder, align, etc.)

Comment: Well, in Illustrator this would be possible via Effects > Distort & Transform > Transform

Comment: You’re absolutely right. Illustrator will have the layout manipulation capabilities.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are correct in your understanding of what I meant, so I have confidence in your answer when you say it can't be done. At least now I know. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you but me understanding the problem doesn't mean my answer will be right. Didn't AAGD have it right?

Comment: His comment relates to Illustrator, but I specifically needed a photoshop solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could actually scale by *numbers* rather than dragging handles. Scaling each rectangle by the same percentage with the origin set at the top left would retain any spacing between them.

[image]

You'd have to scale each layer separately, which may be an issue fr a great many layers. However, if it's just a couple layers, this would work great.

Comment: +1 for this as although as you say it can be a bit long winded for a lot of layers, it is a nice way to consistantly size a number of shapes if there aren't too many. Thanks.